# Store PostgreSQL query into variable

Tags: postgresql

I'm implementing search function, that will serve results to filtering feature.

Is it possible to store intermediate execution results into variable and select from them depending on provided argument to function?

I'm currently stuck on this implementation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.search_companies4(
    head_country_id bigint DEFAULT NULL::bigint,
    name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    "categoryIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[],
    "cityIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[],
    departments public.department[] DEFAULT NULL::public.department[],
    "stockTemperatures" public.stock_temperature[] DEFAULT NULL::public.stock_temperature[],
    verified boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean,
    with_comments boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean
)
RETURNS SETOF public.company
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
AS $$
    declare
        "companies" public.company;
    begin
      if ("search_companies4"."cityIds" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          left join "companyCities" cC ON c.id = cC."companyId"
          where "search_companies4"."cityIds" @> array[cC."cityId"];
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."categoryIds" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          left join "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
          where (
              "search_companies4"."categoryIds" @> array[cCat."categoryId"]
          ) AND (
              "search_companies4"."departments" is null OR
              "search_companies4"."departments" @> array[cCat.department]
          );
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."name" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          where c.name ILIKE "search_companies4"."name";
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."head_country_id" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          where c.head_country_id = "search_companies4"."head_country_id";
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."stockTemperatures" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          where c."stockTemperatures" && "search_companies4"."stockTemperatures";
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."verified" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          left join company_import ci ON c.id = ci.company_id
          where (
              CASE WHEN "search_companies4"."verified" = true THEN
              -- Созданные вручную и проверенные импортированные
              ci.company_id is null OR ci.verified_at is not null
              ELSE true END -- И созданные вручную и все импортированные
          );
      end if;

      if ("search_companies4"."with_comments" is not null) then
          select into "companies" from "companies" AS c
          where (
              CASE WHEN "search_companies4"."with_comments" = true THEN
              -- Только компании с комментариями
              c."lastCommentAt" IS NOT NULL
              ELSE true END
          );
      end if;

      return query select from "companies" order by id;
  end;
$$;
```

It is not working, because PostgreSQL complaints about `companies` variable:

```
ERROR:  relation "companies" does not exist at character 30
QUERY:  select                  from "companies" AS c
left join "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
where (
    "search_companies4"."categoryIds" @> array[cCat."categoryId"]
) AND (
    "search_companies4"."departments" is null OR
    "search_companies4"."departments" @> array[cCat.department]
)
```

How to use this variable to store queries, that can be used with `select` statement step by step?

Or, is there some better implementation…

Comment: You would need a temporary table, you can't do that in a variable

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names